# Removing an item from a list using a variable

Tags: python, list

I'm building a poker game against a bot, and have the card numbers in a list. When the player or bot is given a card I obviously need that card to be deleted from the list so it doesn't get dealt again.

```
def dealPlayer():
    cardSuit = random.randrange(1, 5) #Decide card suit#
    if cardSuit == 1:
        cardNum = random.randrange(0, 13) #Decide card num#
        if cardNum == 11: #Make sure it prints the name not position in list#
            cardNum = "jack"
        elif cardNum == 12:
            cardNum = "queen"
        elif cardNum == 13:
            cardNum = "king"
        elif cardNum == 0:
            cardNum = "ace"
        print ("Your first card is the", cardNum, "of clubs.")
        del Clubs[cardNum] #Problem#
        print(Clubs) #Debugging#
```

The problem I'm having is on the second to last line. Here is the error that it kicks up to me:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Use for the card _name_ a different variable. Name may also mean a number here (maybe converted to a string).

Comment: You should specify if you have 4 cards of each in the vector or what? If not you shouldn't remove it because he can be dealt the same card with different suit. Your quick solution is CLubs.remove(cardNum) but you have other problems there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning a string value to the `cardNum` variable whenever the `cardNum` random value is 0, 11, 12, or 13.

When you access your `Clubs` list after the `cardNum` variable has been set to, say, `"king"`, you are doing essentially this:

```
Clubs["king"]  # Invalid access (str as list index)
```

You are only able to access list indices as integers (0, 1, 2, etc.) and only those indices which are populated in the list (valid indices).

Since the reason you are assigning a string value is for printing, you should just use another variable to store the card name, like so:

```py
def dealPlayer():
    cardSuit = random.randrange(1, 5) #Decide card suit#
    if cardSuit == 1:
        cardNum = random.randrange(0, 14) # Decide card number [0,14), upper exclusive
        if cardNum == 11:
            cardName = "jack"
        elif cardNum == 12:
            cardName = "queen"
        elif cardNum == 13:
            cardName = "king"
        elif cardNum == 0:
            cardName = "ace"
        else:
            cardName = cardNum

        print ("Your first card is the", cardName, "of clubs.")
        Clubs.remove(cardNum)
```

Then you won't have any issues, because `cardNum` remains unchanged and is an integer. Note also, the change to `Clubs.remove(cardNum)`. That is the proper way to remove an item from a list.

### Edit

The logic here is also flawed: as soon as you remove the "three of clubs" (object at index `3` in your case, if `0` is ace) from the list, the list will then be one card shorter, and any cards that come after the "three of clubs" in the list will bump down by one index each. This means that if you are then expecting your object at index `4` to be the "four of clubs" it will actually be the "five of clubs" because everything bumped down by one. You will need to change your design to account for this.

Comment: Isn't that the same as my answer?

Comment: Similar, for sure. I didn't see yours as I was submitting mine. Plus, I also added an explanation.

Comment: Okay then, well.

Comment: Using this method then causes the program to say ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: Oh, it may be because the indices are off for the card "numbers". Since the list is zero-indexed, that would make a Jack correspond to `10`, Queen `11`, and King `12`. It may have been because you were trying to access King at `13` which is out of range of the list. I will edit...

Comment: Also, I realized that your logic is flawed for accessing/removing cards from the list. See my edit.

Comment: You are right about that, but I think your problem might be occurring after you have removed some items from the list, as then the list is shorter, so you will need to lower your random limit to account for less cards being in the list. Otherwise you will be attempting to access an index out of the range of the end of the (now shorter) list. I would suggest changing your design: maybe use a set or a dictionary for your deck.

Comment: I appreciate the help and I am a little annoyed at myself that I didn't catch that I had used numbers that were 1 too high. Thank you. In school I was never taught about sets. They should make this much easier.

Comment: Absolutely. When in doubt, verify that the data structure you are using is suited well for your design. Then you can evaluate a logical approach/algorithm. Happy to help.

Comment: I don't think your numbering is still quite right.  Since 0 is the ace, the numbers 1-10 correspond to the number cards, 11 would be the jack, 12 the queen, and 13 the king.  IOW, there are 14 cards per suit (10 number cards, the jack, queen, king, and ace).  The answer is to expand by 1 on the `randrange()` call.

Comment: Yes, you are right about that. I was flipping the ace out of my mind when thinking that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below as full code:

```
def dealPlayer():
    cardSuit = random.randrange(1, 5) #Decide card suit#
    if cardSuit == 1:
        cardNum = random.randrange(0, 13) #Decide card num#
        if cardNum == 11: #Make sure it prints the name not position in list#
            cardNum_ = "jack"
        elif cardNum == 12:
            cardNum_ = "queen"
        elif cardNum == 13:
            cardNum_ = "king"
        elif cardNum == 0:
            cardNum_ = "ace"
        print ("Your first card is the", cardNum_, "of clubs.")
        del Clubs[cardNum]
        print(Clubs)
```

Change the variable names a bit for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all cardNum is a string. you can do

```
del Clubs[int(cardNum)]
```

But this won't have the result you want, it will delete the index cardNum from the list.
What you want is:

```
Clubs.remove(cardNum)
```

So del removes by index
list.remove() removes by item

Comment: Just like somone else who deleted his answer, this won't works for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are converting cardNum to a string in some circumstances, so the answer is to stop doing that.  Personally, I'd make naming the card a separate method:

```
def cardName(cardNum):
    if cardNum == 11:
        return "jack"
    elif cardNum == 12:
        return "queen"
    elif cardNum == 13:
        return "king"
    elif cardNum == 0:
        return "ace"
    return str(cardNum)


def dealPlayer():
    cardSuit = random.randrange(1, 5) #Decide card suit#
    if cardSuit == 1:
        cardNum = random.randrange(0, 14) #Decide card num#
        print ("Your first card is the", cardName(cardNum), "of clubs.")
        del Clubs[cardNum]
```

Note: your `random.randrange(0, 13)` was wrong, it won't include 13.  You either want to use `random.randrange(0, 14)` or use `random.randint(0, 13)`.

I think you should also consider using sets instead of lists for your card hands and deck, as removal is O(1) vs O(n) for lists.

Also, the way your keeping track of things is not ideal either.  If `Clubs` is meant to be the set of available cards, then you should really be choosing the next card from that set.  Something like:

```
cardNum = random.choice(Clubs)
```

Of course, you need to be careful about your suit selection too.  It's possible that there are no clubs left, in which case you'd need to choose differently.  I think, ideally, you'd keep just a deck instead of separate lists for each suit.  You can use tuples to help you here:

```
deck = set([])
for suit in ["clubs", "spades", "hearts", "diamonds"]:
    for i in range(14):
        deck.add((suit, i))
```

Then remove each card from `deck` as you randomly choose using `random.sample(deck, 1)[0]`:

```
>>> random.sample(deck, 1)[0]
('spades', 9)
```

(it'd be great if you could use `random.choice()` here, but it doesn't accept a set)

Comment: What's wrong with that?  No need to mix it all as one function, especially when half of it is about naming the card. :-)